# What steel to use? What thickness and width? What angles to use?

Tags: steel, carbon-fiber, molding

I am trying to develop my own spring steel version of a carbon fiber running blade that you might see in the paralympics.  Except mine is for someone who still has their foot/leg.  Nothing like that exists and out of necessity I am trying to develop one that is similar and I think i might be able to do it using a less expensive material too.   I really need help calculating what steel to use, thickness, width, angles, etc.  Carbon fiber is ideal but very expensive.  Would spring steel work?  Any concerns with that choice other than a bit heavier?  It would have to be formed in the shape of a "J"This would need to support a 215 pound person walking, running etc.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Determine the load and desired deflection then use Euler beam theory applied to a cantilever (tons of examples on the internet) to give you the cross-sectional shape and size that satisfies that while keeping the stress low enough.

Answer (score 1):

> What steel to use? What thickness and width? What angles to use?

An inexpensive source of spring steel for experimenting with are leaf springs.

[image: Leaf Springs]

You have serious competition, named [Keahi Seymour](https://twitter.com/bionicboots?lang=en) and his 25 mph 'bionic boots'.

[image: Bionic Boots]

There are also [fictional designs](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Long_Fall_Boot) to draw from.

[image: Long Fall Boots]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the spring steel used in cultivator tines for the agricultural industry - lighter than leaf springs and already designed in the vertical orientation you are looking for.

Link to some examples [here](https://www.spaldings.co.uk/replacement-parts/website/replacement-parts/cultivation/heavy-and-light/conventional-spring-s-tines)